# select component via varfile[Unattended mode] when installationtype is Custom - Unix Installer

Tags: install4j

I am using Install4j Unix Installer.

I tried configuring Installation Type 
-Full
-Custom

Also Installation components - where in I have configured two components[Ex: Component1, Compoenent2]  where in user can select b/w the components when **Custom Installation** Type is selected.

Since I am using **Unattended mode with -q** mode, input to the installer is passed via varfile.

I wanted to know how can I chose b/w or which component to install via a VARFILE.

for example, I can chose FULL / CUSTOM installation type via **sys.installationTypeId=Custom**.

In order to test my configuration i did try the same in Windows installer. It does provide a screen - select components to chose b/w components i have configured.

Can I know is there a option to chose a component via varfile, if yes what is the attribute.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select components in the response file with properties like

```
sys.component.1234$Boolean=true
```

where "1234" must be replace with the ID of the component. In this case you need a to set the installation type to "Custom".